# Select count using HQL returns inconsistent results

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, netbeans, glassfish

Alright so, I am currently working on a JSF 2.1 project using NetBeans 7.2.1, Hibernate 3.2.5, GlassFish 3.1.2.2, and MySQL 5.5.20.

I have a button on a page that once clicked, it adds an entry into a table. Upon refreshing the page, another element changes color based on whether or not the button was pressed before, which is determined by doing a `select count(*)` via HQL on the table where the button inserted an entry.

My problem is, the `select count(*)` returns inconsistent results on each refresh. The query is supposed to return either always 0 or always 1 according to my `where` clause and the table data, however it is constantly returning "random" results on each query, even thought the data has not changed after the initial insert.

For instance, if I execute my `select count(*)` query manually on MySQL Workbench, it always returns 1 after the initial insert made via the page button, which is what I expect. On the other hand, Hibernate is randomly returning 0 or 1 on each refresh. here's an example, with each comma being a refresh: 1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0

Does anyone have any clue why `count` isn't returning consistent results? Could it be a caching issue or something?

**If I restart my project in NetBeans** and I access the same page again, then it always returns 1 as expected.

Further testing shows the issue appears to be related to the JDBC connection being in an "uncommitted" state or something, even though the transaction itself is committed successfully.

I apologize if my issue isn't very clear, I am rather confused myself.

---

### Insert code:

```
public boolean reserveBook(int memberId, String isbn)
{
    boolean done = false;

    Transaction tx = null;

    try
    {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();

        Member m = new Member();
        m.setMemberId(memberId);

        Book b = new Book();
        b.setIsbn(isbn);

        Reservation r = new Reservation();
        r.setMember(m);
        r.setBook(b);
        r.setDate(new Date());

        session.save(r);
        tx.commit();

        done = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (tx != null)
        {
            tx.rollback();
        }

        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

    return done;
}
```

---

### Count code:

```
public boolean isBookReserved(int memberId, String isbn)
{
    boolean answer = false;

    String reqHQL = "select count(*) " +
                    "from Reservation R " +
                    "where R.member = :memberId and R.book = :isbn";

    try
    {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery(reqHQL);

        q.setParameter("memberId", memberId);
        q.setParameter("isbn", isbn);

        if ((Long) q.uniqueResult() > 0)
        {
            answer = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }

    return answer;
}
```

---

### Class header:

```
public class BookHelper
{
    private Session session;

    public BookHelper()
    {
        this.session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }
    ...
```

---

### Bean header:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BookBean implements Serializable
{
...
```

Comment: @DavidLevesque : I added the class header. The helper is instantiated in a ManagedBean.

Comment: @DavidLevesque : Added bean header.

Comment: Ok, I was suspecting that the Hibernate session was stored in the HttpSession or reused across requests somehow, but it doesn't seem to be the case :/

Comment: @DavidLevesque : I'm not really sure of what is its purpose, I just started JSF & Hibernate two weeks ago, and that statement is present in just about every get method from the Hibernate tutorial on the NetBeans website.

Comment: @DavidLevesque : All it does is throw this exception : `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session` later on in the code. I had tried that before, but it simply renders the session object useless, which prevents book properties located after the colored element in the XHTML from being read.

Comment: I'm pretty certain it's a caching or syncing issue of some sort from the insert, as if I remove the where clause in the count query, the result randomly alternates between the amount of rows before and after the insert (ex: 4 and 5), until I restart the project.

Answer (score 0):

This situation that is happening with you is very strange. The COUNT should work.

Try debug your code, and verify if the parameters are always the same in each select execution.

PS: there are a closed issue on Hibernate where happened something like that, but in different environments:
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2945

Comment: Further testing shows the issue appears to be related to the JDBC connection being in an "uncommitted" state or something, even though the transaction is committed successfully...